# Use awk to parse input and print multiple columns?

Tags: awk

My input file line format is:

```
themostsimpleproject', branch 'debug_randomnness' : AFFECTED. Affected image discovered: [7.19, 8.37]
```

I want to use awk to print - the project name and the version of the affected image.
Example:

```
themostsimpleproject 7.19, 8.37
```

How can i do it in awk. I will prefer a simple code that i can execute over command line. Ex: `awk -F"\," 'print $1 $4'`. But a simple script is also welcome.

Note: i don't want to print the `'` at the end of project name.

Comment: The question is not very clear about possible input variants. As the question stands, you could even use some `cut -c ...`.

Comment: 1 line of sample input isn't enough for us to be able to guess at a way to parse your data in general. Please a) tell us how to parse it (first word after a `:` or part of 4th word after a `'` or string from position 35-42 or whatever that is, etc.) and b) provide 5-10 lines of various sample input that covers all of your use cases and the expected output given that input.

Comment: You should show what you have tried so far, and explain why that's not effective for you.  Stack Exchange isn't a code-to-order service!

Comment: ... and if it was, the current equivalent of ordering "some kind of liquid" at a Starbucks drive-through would produce the equivalent results :-).

Answer (score 3):

Try this using `awk`:

```
awk -F "[]'[]" '/: AFFECTED/{print $1, $(NF-1)}' input
```

- `-F` defines the field separator (FS). It is a [regex string](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Regexp-Field-Splitting.html), which includes a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) (`[..]`), meaning "any one of the characters included in the character class" is a field separator.

  - The characters chosen here are `'`,`[` or `]`.
  - The `]` must be in first place to avoid it being seen as closing character. (You could also escape!)
- the first field `$1` ends at the first `'`, so the project name is  `$1`
- Affected versions is `$(NF-1)`. As `]` is the last character, `$NF` would be empty.

Output:

```
themostsimpleproject 7.19, 8.37
```

This will search for rows with String `: AFFECTED` and then output all image versions, even if there are more affected than just 2.

Comment: Can you explain your FS value please? `-F "['[]|]"` won't be very clear to users.

Comment: `-F"[][']"` maybe so? Or `-F"[]'[]"`

Comment: @pLumo, works like blaze. +1. I want to complicate it. But i will post it as new Q and inform you here. Or will edit this Q.

Comment: You can edit your Q :-)

Comment: Didn't know that you can put it in front, good to know.

Answer (score 1):

```
 awk -F "'" '{gsub(/:.*:/,"",$NF);gsub(/[\]\[]/,"",$NF);print $1,$NF}' filename
```

output

```
themostsimpleproject   7.19 8.37
```

Answer (score 1):

Also with `awk`:

```
awk '{gsub(/[][]/,"");gsub(/[[:punct:]]/,"",$1);print $1, $(NF-1),$NF}' file
themostsimpleproject 7.19, 8.37
```

- we remove `[` and `]` with `gsub()` and all punctuation of the field1.
- and then we print first field and two last fields.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `sed`:

```bsh
$ sed "s/^\(.*\)',.*\[\(.*\)\]$/\1 \2/" file
themostsimpleproject 7.19, 8.37
```

Or with GNU version

```bsh
$ sed -E "s/^(.*)',.*\[(.*)\]$/\1 \2/" file 
themostsimpleproject 7.19, 8.37
```